# PL/SQL Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Just started doing some PL/SQL and I need some help creating a procedure I was assigned to practice:

> Create a procedure that has two inputs - firstname and surname. The
>   procedure should DBMS output the following 3 lines:
>
> ```
> firstname surname (lowercase) 
> FIRSTNAME SURNAME (uppercase) Firstname 
> Surname (Initial uppercase)
> ```
>
> The following PL/SQL functions can be used to assist:
>
> ```
> UPPER( VARCHAR2 ), LOWER(VARCHAR2), INITCAP( VARCHAR2 )
> ```

I've tried this so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LabFourProc (firstname IN VARCHAR2, surname IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(firstname, surnmame);
END LabFourProc;
/
```

Comment: what have you tried so far, as you have the 3 functions you require. its a trivial procedure to write given that you've been told the three functions to use.

Comment: I've tried this so far:
"CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LabFourProc (firstname 
 IN VARCHAR2, surname IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(firstname, surnmame); 
END LabFourProc;
/"

Obviously it didn't work though, I'm very new to this!

Comment: @user2252636 the best way to show your code is the edit link below your question.  PL/SQL has [comprehensive documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/toc.htm) available for free online, the syntax of procedures is described in [the PL/SQL Subprograms section](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm#i4079).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mate I'm new to this as well .Try this , if this helps

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LabFourProc (firstname IN VARCHAR2, surname IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE (1000000); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Input Parameters:'|| firstname ||CHR(9)|| surname ||CHR(10)||
'Upper Name:' || upper(firstname)||CHR(9)||upper(surname)||CHR(10)||
'Lower Name:' || lower(firstname)||CHR(9)||lower(surname)||CHR(10)||
'First Leter Cap Name:' || initcap(firstname)||CHR(9)||initcap(surname));
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CONCAT()` function or the `||` operator to join strings.  For example:

```
-- outputs "firstname surname"
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(firstname || ' ' || surnmame);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
p1(fn varchar2, sn varchar2)
is
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lower(fn)||' '||lower(sn)||','||upper(fn)||' '||upper(sn)||','||initcap(fn)||' '||initcap(sn));
END;
```

Execution

```
EXEC P1('ANYA','ROMANOVA');
```